# Java JUnit Testing for Method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am new at JUnit Testing and curious about how it works. Currently I am trying to get an unit test to pass.

The test Method is

```
@Test
  public void ensure_equals_method_is_properly_coded ()
  {
    assertTrue(employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(2)));
    assertFalse(employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(1)));
    assertFalse(employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(3)));
  }
```

I have an ArrayList already populated with values in it. From what I understand I am suppose to write a method called equals() to get this test to pass for my task. My question is how will this method find the method to test against. I have created an equals() method in a class called Persons but I don't know if it's even being called when I run the test.

My second question is questioning the logic in my equal() method. So far I have this.

```
public boolean equals() {
      if (employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(2))) 

          return true;
    return false;
  }
```

This should return true because the first test item asserts that is true. Is my logic correct on this?

just for clarity here is my full Test class everything is already there.

```
public class Tests 
{
  List<Person> employees = new ArrayList<Person>();

  @Before
  public void init ()
  {
    Person anEmployee = new Employee();
    anEmployee.setName("Trevor Page");
    anEmployee.setSex("Male");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(1983, 0, 1);
    anEmployee.setBirthday(cal.getTime());
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setJobTitle("Sr. Software Engineer");
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setOrganization(new Google("Google"));
    employees.add(anEmployee);

    anEmployee = new Employee();
    anEmployee.setName("Jane Doe");
    anEmployee.setSex("Female");
    anEmployee.setBirthday(cal.getTime());
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setJobTitle("Sr. Software Engineer");
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setOrganization(new Google("Google"));
    employees.add(anEmployee);

    anEmployee = new Employee();
    anEmployee.setName("Trevor Page");
    anEmployee.setSex("Male");
    anEmployee.setBirthday(cal.getTime());
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setJobTitle("Sr. Software Engineer");
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setOrganization(new Google("Google"));
    employees.add(anEmployee);

    anEmployee = new Employee();
    anEmployee.setName("Trevor Page");
    anEmployee.setSex("Male");
    anEmployee.setBirthday(cal.getTime());
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setJobTitle("Sr. Software Engineer");
    ((Employee)anEmployee).setOrganization(new Microsoft("Microsoft"));
    employees.add(anEmployee);
  }

  @Test
  public void ensure_toString_method_is_properly_coded()
  {
    String message = "Name: Trevor Page, Sex: Male" +
    "\nJob Title: Sr. Software Engineer, Organization: Google";

    assertThat(employees.get(0).toString(), is(message));
  }

  @Test
  public void ensure_equals_method_is_properly_coded ()
  {
    assertTrue(employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(2)));
    assertFalse(employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(1)));
    assertFalse(employees.get(0).equals(employees.get(3)));
  }
```

Here is my full Persons Class which is Abstract. I already have the first test case working.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public abstract class Person 
{
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract String getSex();
  public abstract void setName(String name);
  public abstract void setSex(String sex);
  public abstract void setBirthday(Date birthdate);
  public abstract Date getBirthday();
  public abstract String getJobTitle();
  public abstract String getNameOfOrganization();



  List<Person> employees = new ArrayList<Person>();



  @Override
  public String toString() {  


    return "Name: " + getName() + ", Sex: " + getSex() + "\n" + "Job Title: " + getJobTitle() + ", Organization: " + getNameOfOrganization() ;

     }

}
```

I have another class called Employee the extends this Abstract Class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee extends Person

{

    List<String> employees = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        employees.add("Trevor Page");

        return employees.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSex() {

        employees.add("Male");
        return employees.get(1);

    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setBirthday(Date birthdate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Date getBirthday() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public String getJobTitle() {

        employees.add("Sr. Software Engineer");

        return employees.get(2);
    }

    public void setOrganization(Google google) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setOrganization(Microsoft microsoft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String getNameOfOrganization() {
        employees.add("Google");
        return employees.get(3);
    }

}
```

I was able to get the first test to work by luck. Im not sure how the unit test knows to test my values.

Comment: Not clear, where did you program that equals method?

Comment: on a abstract class named Person.

Comment: and where is the variable called `employees` defined?

Comment: This all on the Test.Java class                                List<Person> employees = new ArrayList<Person>();

Comment: So be clear.  Are you testing the equivalence of a `Person`, or are you testing the equivalence of an `Employee`?  You're kind of munging the two of them together here.

Comment: A Person since the There are two separate in the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented `equals` in the person class, then you can assert if two persons are equal.

What you have above is equivalent to

```
Person p1 = employees.get(0);
Person p2 = employees.get(2);
assertTrue(p1.equals(p2));
```

Above, you invoke the equals method directly.

But you may just as well do

```
assertEquals(p1,p2);
```

In whose case the `Person.equals` method is invoked under the hood.

The methods `assertEquals`, `assertTrue`, `assertFalse` and a few others can be statically imported from `org.junit.Assert` class, somewhat like:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Or the much simpler form `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

You implementation of equals should simply verify if one employee is equal to another, it should not know about list of employees as you seem to imply.

For instance

```
class Person {
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if(this==o) {
         return true; 
      }
      if(o instanceof Person) {
         Person other = (Person) o;
         return (this.name == other.name) || (this.name != null && this.name.equals(other.name);
      }
      reurn false;
   }
}
```

Your testing would consist in verifying that this `equals` implementation is correct, in other words, that it satisfies properties like simmetry, transitivity and reflexivity, etc. Refer to the javadocs of `Object.equals` method to know more about this.

Comment: The Asserts are all on the Test Class.

Answer (score 0):

What edwin said. Also:

The test should be calling equals and asserting the returned boolean value.

It might be confusing to do that, since there is no obvious way to setup the employees value. The usual method is to have the employees field package visible (no accessibility modifier) and the Test class in the same package as the class under test.

Edit: If the Person class is abstract, consider creating a concrete sub-class as a sample that allows you to unit test the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by stating that your `equals` method is **not** being called in the test.  You are effectively calling `Object.equals(Object o)` instead of `Person.equals()`.  Do you notice the difference in the signature?  Your `equals` method doesn't take a parameter, which is unusual - you should be comparing equivalence to *something* else.

Also, the set up of your test is inappropriate. You should establish a **unit** of test data to validate against.  Do away with unnecessary data structures; I mean you're only ever comparing two objects in an `equals()` call.

Let's fix these two issues.

Your `equals` method needs to override `Object.equals`.  To do that, you make a method that has the same signature.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // What makes two Person instances equivalent?
}
```

I'll leave this implementation up to you.  Take into account the case in which `other` is `null`.

Next, the test.  The way I prefer setting up my tests are in small chunks.  There are several facets to verify when testing this logic:

- Do the two instances have the same values?
- Do they have the same value for `hashCode()`?  (This is a convention, that if two objects are equal, then their hashCode is equal.)
- Are they equal if the instances is different?  E.G.  comparing a `Person` to an `Integer` should be...
- Are they equal if one of the instances is `null`?

At the minimum, this is four test cases.

```
@Test
public void equals_equivalentInstances() {
    // given
    // two objects that are initialized in the exact same way
    // when + then
    // call the equals() method and assert that the statement is true
}


@Test
public void equals_hashCodeMatches() {
    // given
    // two objects that are initialized in the exact same way
    // when + then
    // call the hashCode() method of both and assert their equivalence
}


@Test
public void equals_handlesDifferentObjectTypes() {
    // given
    // a Person class and some other Object
    // when + then
    // call the equals() method and assert that they are not equal
}

@Test
public void equals_handlesNull() {
    // given
    // two Person classes, one of them initialized to null
    // when + then
    // call the equals() method and assert that they are not equal
}
```